# Assertion 'clock_gettime(map_clock_id(clock_id), &ts) == 0' failed at ../src/basic/time-util.c:55, function now(). Aborting

Tags: linux, apt, libraries, clock

As per [this naswer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688034/after-libc6-upgrade-sudo-account-validation-failure-is-your-account-locked/688039?noredirect=1#comment1300941_688039) I have tried to fix a failed libc6 and libcrypto update.  I created a link where it seemed appropriate by

1. mounting my SD card onto `/media` on another PC
2. changed directory to `/media/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`
3. created the link with `sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.1  libcrypto.so.1`

The available library files now read

```
>l ./libcrypt*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 1.4M Mar  1  2019 ./libcrypto.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   38 Oct  3  2019 ./libcrypt.so -> /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  42K Oct  3  2019 ./libcrypt.a
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 2.1M Dec 24 07:15 ./libcrypto.so.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   16 Dec 24 07:15 ./libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 3.4M Dec 24 07:15 ./libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   16 Jan 27 12:41 ./libcrypto.so.1 -> libcrypto.so.1.1
```

When I rebooted my raspebrry Pi I got a number of services returning "FAILED" (too fast to read) and no login prompt.

Now the screen is full of `Assertion 'clock_gettime(map_clock_id(clock_id), &ts) == 0' failed at ../src/basic/time-util.c:55, function now(). Aborting.`

This error message does not give much on google, and I am not even sure it is related to my fix or to the original issue of failed upgrade of libc6 and libcrypto. Anybody knows what this error is and how to deal with it?

Comment: As to the assertion, you may have made a bit more damage than first thought. That call, `clock_gettime`, is part of vdso and is memory mapped by the kernel.

Comment: I think you are missing a file, from my own system:

`/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1`


I'm not sure `./libcrypt.so` should point to `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1`.